# Database Tables for User management

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to get some advice from you about best practices in user role management.

I would like to create an application where user register and will have different roles. Now the obvious thing is, to create the users table and save the user data there like this:

**users**

- id
- userUUID
- username
- role

But I think about separated tables for different groups. So like:

**admins**

- id
- userUUID (-> foreign key users table)
- accessRight1
- accessRight2

**subscribers**

- id
- userUUID (-> foreign key users table)
- etc

Does this make sense? So should all users, regardless of their role be in one database? And what is then about the specific information for different roles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your roles are rarely going to change that would probably work.  But, you should always plan for change, and a more flexible option allowing you to add roles without needing to change your database schema would be something like this:

**Users:**

- uid
- user info...

**Roles:**

- rid
- name

**UserRoles:**

- uid (FK to user table)
- rid (FK to roles table)

In your code you could then check the UserRoles table to determine if the user has a given role and therefore should be allowed to do whatever.

Additionally, if you want to mix and match permissions for actions across multiple roles (i.e. both Admin's and Moderators have permission to delete posts or something).  You could add another level with a **Permissions** table, and a join table (**RolePermissions**) linking that to the Roles table.  You're access checks would become slightly more complicated then, requiring you to join the **UserRoles** table and **RolePermissions** join table to determine if a user has a given permission to do something.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM UserRoles u INNER JOIN RolePermissions p 
        ON u.rid=p.rid 
    WHERE u.ID=<USER> AND p.pid=<PERMISSION>
```